# python requests get after clicking data

Tags: python, html, iframe, request

my code

```py
res = requests.get(url='https://myself-bbs.com/thread-45431-1-1.html', headers=headers).text
html = BeautifulSoup(res, features='lxml')
for i in html.find_all('ul', class_='main_list'):
    print(i)
```

result

```py
<ul class="main_list"><li>
<a href="javascript:;">第 01 話</a>
" href="#" target="_blank">站內</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li>
...........
```

Event triggered after web page click.

I want to get this!

`<a href="#" data-href="https://v.myself-bbs.com/player/play/45431/001 "target="_blank" class="various fancybox.iframe">In the station</a>`

How to get ?

Attach pictures.

[image][image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the select method to catch the url .

```py
for i in html.select('ul.main_list'):
    for j in i.find_all('a', href='javascript:;'):
        title = j.text
        for k in j.parent.select("ul.display_none li"):
            a = k.select_one("a[data-href*='v.myself-bbs.com']")
            if k.select_one("a").text == '站內':
                url = a["data-href"].replace('player/play', 'vpx').replace("\r", "").replace("\n", "")
                print(url)
```